# How to migrate "log-in with Google" to Microsoft

Tags: office365, migration, google-workspace

I'm looking to migrate from Google Workspace to Office 365 but before I do I want to know how to handle the third-party websites (like Stackexchange) that use the sign-in with Google feature.

I've spent a fair bit of time searching for answers and have turned up no writing/thinking on this (including Microsoft's migration guide)

Comment: I'm in the same boat, have the same questions, and have also turned up nothing. Did you manage to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope. I think I'll just go through support teams on each service.

Comment: Damn! Thanks for letting me know though, and good luck!